# Python-Telegram-Bot not running behind firewall

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've been searching about this for several days to no avail. I have a python bot ( polling for updates)  running OK at home or any public internet. However,  when at work behind a firewall, the bot cannot connect to the server. I believe that the application must know the proxy server, user ID and password in order to proceed. But I cannot a find the way or how to include this info in the bot application. Below is the error message:

```
2017-03-13 07:13:44,233 - telegram.ext.updater - ERROR - Error
while getting Updates: urllib3 HTTPError HTTPSConnectionPool
(host='api.telegram.org', port=443):Max retries exceeded with
url: /botXXXXXXXXX:Token/getUpdates (Caused byNewConnectionError
('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031541F0>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection
could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

/getUpdates (Caused by NewConnectionError      ('

Other thing: The Telegram  messenger application runs OK behind this same firewall without any info on the proxy server. So it can connect to the server with no problem. I mention this because another cause could be my company uses websense or something like that to block the telegram server , but it is not the case as the messenger application  do work OK.

Thanks a million in advance for any hint.

UPDATE JULY 26th, 2017:  The solution was as suggested by Sudheesh. The environmental variables https_proxy needs to be set. At the time of this answer it seems to be I've entered the wrong proxy server or in the wrong way. looking around internet ,  I've noticed the way to set this is (in windows)  is:

set https_proxy=http://proxy_url

Notice the right side of the equal show http ( not https)

Thanks to Sudheesh again!

Comment: You can `export http_proxy=` and `export https_proxy=` on the commandline before running the bot.

Comment: Sudeesh, Thanks,  I will try that, but what about the USERID and PSW?

Comment: I did that but now the bot will not start. It throws several errors, the last is:     raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None

Comment: Which proxy  scheme are you using?

Comment: I really do not know. The server requires  an userID and Psw. Do you know a command or test I can run to find out the scheme?